# Upgraded to 16.04 and now chjail ssh forwarding doesn't work

Tags: dns, sshd, socks5

I've been doing tunneling of my web traffic for years now using the [PuTTY -> Ubuntu server -> internet method](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/use-putty-as-a-secure-proxy-on-windows/) for a while.  (BTW, the article linked is not the article I specifically used WAY back in the day but the concepts are the same.)

One thing I added to this set up was [chroot jail](http://allanfeid.com/content/creating-chroot-jail-ssh-access) using the article linked.  The exception I made was, of course, setting `AllowTcpForwarding` to `yes`

However, after upgrading to 16.04, the proxy stopped working...sort of.  Sites that are resolved in /etc/hosts work fine but sites that weren't would kind of get blocked.  When I inspected the PuTTY event log, I got the following error:

```
2016-09-02 12:48:45 Opening connection to en.wikipedia.org:443 for forwarding from 127.0.0.1:52413
2016-09-02 12:48:45 Forwarded connection refused by server: Administratively prohibited [open failed]
```

Everything works correctly if I log in as a non-chjailed user.  This leads me to believe that the chjailed user cannot resolve DNS queries, which wasn't the case before.  My guess is that the upgraded sshd daemon stops DNS queries now.  I'm not sure how to confirm this for sure but when I try to visit wikipedia via it's IP address, I can connect.

Some unique things in my set up: the same server I'm ssh'ing into has dnsmasq set up to do DNS caching among other things.  dnsmasq works correctly as expected.

What has changed in the new sshd that would prevent DNS resolution?  What libraries do I need to add to re-enable it for the chjailed user?

Thanks

Comment: What version did you upgrade *from*? I honestly know nothing about chrooted environments, but I wonder if the change to resolvconf (which happened around 12.04 iirc) is significant? In particular, that `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` - can your chroot jail handle that?

Comment: I upgraded from 14.04.  It looks like I never had a chjail version of the resolv.conf file.  I'll copy that and see if that helps things.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply.  Copying /etc/resolv.conf did not resolve the issue.